# How to add to the values across individual specific rows of an array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm very new to coding and have searched heavily to try to find an answer to this.

I have a (10,10) array and am trying to add across two specific rows a specific value. I am also trying to do it with a single line of code.

Specifically, I am trying to add across the sixth and 8th row of the array the value present at the specific element of that same array (5,5). My array is defined as 'a'.

I feel like a for loop could work, but the problem is that 1) this is two lines of code, and 2, it produces something close but is adding that element to those two rows, twice instead of once.

```
for x in a[(5,7),:]:    
    a[(5,7),:] = (x + (a[5,5])):
```

Comment: what do you mean by "(10, 10) array"? is it a matrix? is it a tuple?

Comment: My apologies, it is just a simple matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably over-complicated this a bit. If I understand correctly, you should do something like this:

```
a[(5, 7), :] += a[5, 5]
```

The `+=` operator is an "in-place" addition. This is the same as doing this:

```
a[(5, 7), :] = a[(5, 7), :] + a[5, 5]
```

Comment: Dang. This is all it is? I'll need to sit and think about this for a bit but I appreciate it!

Comment: @421543 That's the beauty of `numpy` broadcasting for you

Comment: Thanks for answering the question--a follow-up. I guess I am having trouble with the fact that with this line of code, we redefining those two rows in the original array based setting them equal to a new array that is only two rows in size (in other words, why does it add them in a particular order to the old array (i.e., 5 then 7 instead of vice versa). This question may be colored by my poor understanding of coding.

Comment: @421543 Also, `a[5, 5]` isn't an array it's a single value. Adding it to the array is basically doing the loop for you, that's what `numpy` does

Comment: I am so new I can't yet upvote, but I will come back and do it when I am able to!